# Добавление результата запроса в таблицу

Tags: mysql, sql

Каким образом можно добавить результат данного запроса в таблицу?

```
    SELECT `class`, `discipline`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_students`, 0)) AS `count_students`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лекция', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lection`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Семинар', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `seminar`,
    SUM(IF(`type`='Лабораторная', `count_hours`, 0)) AS `lab`,
    SUM(`type`='Лекция') AS `groups`,
    SUM(`type`='Лабораторная') AS `subgroups`,
    count('id') AS `numbe`,
    `course_semestr`, `profile`, `id`
FROM
    `list`
GROUP BY
    `class`,
    `discipline
```

Создал таблицу с точно такими же названиями столбцов, и теперь нужно результат запроса сохранить в эту таблицу. Как это можно сделать через sql?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name SELECT...` пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1(f1,f2,f3)
SELECT x1, x2, x3 FROM table2
```

Здсь имена не важны, а важен порядок полей

Comment: На 1 секунду опередили )

Comment: В SELECT поля должны идти в той же последовательности, что и в INSERT? Т.е F1 будет соответствовать X1, F2 = X2 и т.д?

Comment: @ШамильАсланов, если вы поля задаете явно, то как задали, так в `select\`е` они и должны идти. Если поля опустили, то в select\`е должен быть порядок полей, указанный при создании таблицы.

Comment: Т.е если допустим в SELECT у меня идет: `class`, `discipline`, то и в INSERT у меня будет идти `class`, `discipline`, а не наоборот

Comment: Да, правильно, наоборот нельзя (как mysql может догадаться о ваших намерениях?)